# Connect node app and server + post image to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server

I have a very basic question about a node application, and a question about HTTP requests. It's the first time I create a node app with server, and I just can't seem to get the different components to work together.

This is my server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
const request = require('request');

const upload = multer({dest: __dirname + '/uploads/images'});

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.post('/upload', upload.single('photo'), (req, res) => {
    if(req.file) {
        res.json(req.file);
    }
    else throw 'error';
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Listening at ' + PORT );
});
```

Then I have a file app.js with a motion-detection system. Every time motion is detected, a picture is taken. This all works fine.
Then the picture should be sent to the server. This is what I can't figure out.
I created a function `toServer()` that should post the detected data to the server

```
const request = require('request');    
function toServer(data) {
      const formData = {
      // Pass data via Buffers
      my_buffer: data,
      // Pass optional meta-data with an 'options' object with style: {value: DATA, options: OPTIONS}
      // Use case: for some types of streams, you'll need to provide "file"-related information manually.
      // See the `form-data` README for more information about options: https://github.com/form-data/form-data
    
      };
      request.post({url:'http://localhost:3000/upload', formData: formData}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
        if (err) {
          return console.error('Upload failed:', err);
        }
        console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
      });
    };
```

**Problem 1**: when running the server.js on localhost:3000, it doesn't find any of the scripts loaded in index.html nor my app.js.
**Problem 2**: when running the index.html on live-server, all scripts are found, but i get the error "request is not defined".

I am pretty sure there is some basic node setup thing I'm missing.
The solution for `toServer()` might be more complicated.

Thanks for your time,
Mustard Shaper

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:

this could happen because you have not specified to render your index.html.
for example:

```js
res.render('index')
```

if it's not because of the single quotes in upload.single('photo') try double quotes.

Another possible error could be that you are missing a default display engine setting.
an example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/hbs

Problem 2:
it may be because you are missing the header

```js
var request = require('request');
request.post({
  headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  url:     'http://localhost',
  body:    "example"
}, function(error, response, body){
  console.log(body);
});
```

See more at https://expressjs.com/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your suggestions didn't really change anything.
Where do you suggest to add the 'res.render('index')'?

Comment: That depends a lot on what you want to do, for example if you want to display a view in the main path of your project, the 
res.render('index')
 would go in
 app.get('/' "here is your logic and render");